# How do I get rid of the forrest reflection in my glass surface?

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting, glass

[image]

Hello, so I'm attempting to use glassy surfaces for the first time. My aim is to see the brown roof in the house from the outside. Therefore full Transmission is required.
The problem is that I can't get rid of that forrest reflection in the windows. I tried to change the hdri enviromental picture, but it's still there.
Is there a way to get ridd of it?

[image]

Comment: If you are in Eevee, try to go into the Render panel > Indirect Ligthing > Delete Lighting Cache

Comment: Does this appear on Render or only on Material Preview Viewport Shading?

Comment: @moonboots Iam in Evee, but unfortunately I cannot select delete lighting Cache. I'm not able to press it, so it's no option

Comment: maybe pack your images and share your file?

Comment: r u using an hdri?

Comment: @moonbots its uploaded

Comment: @Chris I changed the hdri, but this reflection didn't change from the beginning. It's infact a completely different hdri at the moment. It doesn't make sense that the one is reflected which is on the pic

Comment: @FFeller happens in viewport mode and render mode